# How to replace POI images in the ARView

Tags: android, image, point-of-interest

I'm running an Wikitude application which shows the point if Interest
(POIs). When the application starts, I click a button to launch ARView
(AUgmented Reality) and there I could see the POI images superimposed
on the Live Camera images.

Now I want to change those images at frequent intervals.

I'm using :

```
// Need handler for callbacks to the UI thread  
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();  

// Create runnable for posting
final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       updateResultsInUi();
   }
};

protected void startLongRunningOperation() {

   // Fire off a thread to do some work
   Thread t = new Thread() {
       public void run() {
           Pi.computePi(800).toString(); //Do something for a while
           mHandler.post(mUpdateResults); //then update image
       }
   };
   t.start();
}
```

But nothing is working. I'm sure I'm doing some mistake...

Thanking you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you are running a "Wikitude application", do you mean you are building an app using their publicly available on-device Android API (http://www.wikitude.org/developers)? If so, then dynamically changing the POI marker images is not supported. The AR view is an activity within the Wikitude app itself, launched via your intent. You have no further POI control (apart from callback intents) after the camera view is launched.

Answer (score 0):

We can add our customized icons for a Point of Interest. Have you gone through the sample code provided by Wikitude?. There you can find a method startARViewWithIcons(). Just go through it once, Let me know if there is anything else....  Thanks & Regards, Raghavendra K